# django-mptt raises 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tree_id' when saving node

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

[image: screen shot 2016-07-20 at 17 06 39]

Environment: python 2.7.10, Django 1.9.1, django-mptt 0.8.4

```
# models.py
class Foo(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

Error raises in:

```
getattr(self, opts.tree_id_attr) != getattr(parent, opts.tree_id_attr)
```

where parent is `None` because of:

1) [link](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/0.8.x/mptt/models.py#L892)

```
opts.set_raw_field_value(self, opts.parent_attr, old_parent_id) # old_parent_id is None
```

2) [link](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/0.8.x/mptt/models.py#L900)

```
parent = getattr(self, opts.parent_attr)
```

[set_raw_field_value source:](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/0.8.x/mptt/models.py#L109)

```
def set_raw_field_value(self, instance, field_name, value):
    field = instance._meta.get_field(field_name)
    setattr(instance, field.attname, value)
```

Help me to understand this behavior. Why it's not enough to set relation by `self.parent_id`?

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that setting parent_id does not reset parent in any way,
>   resp. parent isn't dynamically loaded from the database just because
>   the underlying id field has some value.

https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/issues/428